# Windows Mobile: How to get MFC DLLs in Setup CAB (vs2008)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, windows-mobile, setup-deployment, pocketpc

We have an old Windows Mobile MFC app which is undergoing some upgrades. We're building with Visual Studio 2008. When we connect the device and deploy to it and it runs fine. When this happens, vs2008 deploys three run-time DLLs: atl90.dll, mfc90u.dll and msvcr90.dll to the device.

When using a desktop setup project in Visual Studio, run time dependencies are correctly identified and installed. This doesn't seem to be the case with mobile projects using MFC. When we use a Setup CAB project, it does not include any runtime DLLS, and subsequently, the application fails to launch because those files are missing. Is this a known limitation of VS2008?

The only solution I've managed to find is to statically link all the MFC and runtime libraries. This, however, makes the CAB file about 4x larger which is really not that desirable.

Is there a mfc redistributable that can be included in a CAB file for windows mobile?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  It's not in the most intuitive location, though.  Check your dev PC here:

`%PROGRAM_FILES%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\ce\dll`